Method invocation failed
Attempted to export folder structure and permissions from one of the shared drives.
We were provided with the below mentioned script, however, we are being prompt with an error on Line 24.
This is the error:
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Temp\Export Folder Structure with Permissions v2.ps1:24 char:12
+            $permissionsData += $permissionData
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

This is the script that was ran.
It is support to export CSV with columns:
Column A: FolderPath
Column B: IdentityReference
Column C: AccessControlType
Column D: InheritanceFlags
Column E: PropagationFlags
Column: F FileSyStemRights

This is the Script:
# Define the root folder path
$rootFolder = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder"
# Define the output CSV file path
$outputFile = "C:\Path\To\Output\permissions.csv"
# Create an empty array to store permission data
$permissionsData = @()
# Function to recursively get and export permissions
function Export-Permissions {
   param (
       [string]$folderPath
   )
   $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath
   foreach ($item in $items) {
       $permissions = Get-Acl -Path $item.FullName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access
       foreach ($permission in $permissions) {
           $permissionData = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
               "FolderPath" = $item.FullName
               "IdentityReference" = $permission.IdentityReference
               "AccessControlType" = $permission.AccessControlType
               "InheritanceFlags" = $permission.InheritanceFlags
               "PropagationFlags" = $permission.PropagationFlags
               "FileSystemRights" = $permission.FileSystemRights
           }
           $permissionsData += $permissionData
       }
       Export-Permissions -folderPath $item.FullName
   }
}
# Start the export
Export-Permissions -folderPath $rootFolder`enter code here`
# Export the data to a CSV file
$permissionsData | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "Permissions exported to $outputFile


Looks like you forgot to post the script. In any case, the error tells you what's wrong: $permissionData contains a [PSCustomObject] instance, and [PSCustomObject] + [PSCustomObject] doesn't have any meaningful definition

Sorry, I just added the script for better visuals

It's suppose to export permissions with the attributes "FolderPath," "IdentityReference," "AccessControlType," "InheritanceFlags," "PropagationFlags," and "FileSystemRights" from a folder and its subfolders to csv

Avoid += altogether - simply output the permission object(s) one by one as you go along:
# Define the root folder path
$rootFolder = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder"
# Define the output CSV file path
$outputFile = "C:\Path\To\Output\permissions.csv"

function Export-Permissions {
    param (
        [string]$folderPath
    )

    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        $permissions = Get-Acl -Path $item.FullName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access
        foreach ($permission in $permissions) {
            # just let the output object(s) bubble up to the caller - no need to collect anything
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'FolderPath'        = $item.FullName
                'IdentityReference' = $permission.IdentityReference
                'AccessControlType' = $permission.AccessControlType
                'InheritanceFlags'  = $permission.InheritanceFlags
                'PropagationFlags'  = $permission.PropagationFlags
                'FileSystemRights'  = $permission.FileSystemRights
            }
        }

        if ($item -is [DirectoryInfo]) {
            Export-Permissions -folderPath $item.FullName
        }
    }
}

Export-Permissions -folderPath $rootFolder |Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation


I Will test this and confirm if it helped.
